# JSF rerender clears html code added onload

Tags: jsf, rerender

I add a checkbox in front of specific components like dropdowns on page load. When a particular dropdown on change reRenders the a4j:outputPanel which has the checkbox, the checkox disappears. Is it because of the view being created and then I have added the checkbox. OR the a4j:outputPanel is the cause. I cannot remove the panel. Can anyone please guide me?

P.S : If I dont reRender the a4j:outputPanel the checkbox remains. But I need to reRender the panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it disappears is that as you said it is added using javascript. When you render an element using jsf + ajax the element is created from the response from server. As the server knows nothing about your onload code, it removes the element and recreates it with response from server.